# OTP is read from message without set oneTimeCode to Textfield

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS 12 or higher, there is a new capability for read OTP from messages.

The question is, if i add in view a UITextField (with default configuration, not setting new otp capability), why OTP is displayed in autocorrect bar?

*Note: XCode 10.2, Swift 4*

**Detail Explanation**

OTP, is one time password or one time pin.

From **iOS 12**, a new `textContentType` was added to `ÙITextInputTraits`.
This is `oneTimeCode`.
That's allow to read from sms a code and puts into a view above of the keyboard (Suggestion part).

The line must be put like this:

```swift
otpTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

**Note:** This only works with native Keyboard

But, it is not necessary when you use a textfield default configuration, because, when you receive the sms with your one time password, you don't need to remember that, because it's showed into suggestion bar. **(Tested)**

So, you can paste one time code in whatever TextField. 
Only if you set `autocorrect` to false, this attribute set is an advantage.